# Set CSS class for a tree item, retaining the css already applied on other tree items

Tags: vaadin, jstree, vaadin7

I have a tree comprising steps and substeps for completing an application. With a tree item selection, a form page opens next to it. Once the form is filled up and next is clicked, with successful validation of form filling, the next tree gets selected and the previous one gets marked with a tick, specifying this substep has been completed. I hope i cleared my question. Kindly suggest me to achieve the same. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

https://vaadin.com/api/7.2.2/com/vaadin/ui/Tree.ItemStyleGenerator.html can be used:

e.g.: this marks all steps before the current one with the style `done`:

```
    final steps = ['Step 1', 'Step 2', 'Step 3'].asImmutable()
    def currentStep = 0

    final tree = new Tree()
    tree.setItemStyleGenerator({ Tree source, Object itemId ->
        steps.findIndexOf{it==itemId}<currentStep ? 'done' : ''
    } as Tree.ItemStyleGenerator)
    steps.each{ tree.addItem(it) }
    tree.setSelectable(true)
    tree.value = steps.first()

    final nextButton = new Button('Next', {
        currentStep = (currentStep+1)%steps.size()
        tree.value = steps[currentStep]
    } as Button.ClickListener)

    final layout = new HorizontalLayout(tree, nextButton)
```

css:

```
.v-tree-node-done {
  background-color: green;
}
```